Match a partial object with node:assert / assert arguments of mocked function
I have a mock and want to make sure that it was called with a specific set of arguments. However, I do not want to loop through all calls first.
it("should assert args", (t) => {
  const loggerSpy = t.mock.method(Logger, "info");
  myFunctionUnderTest();
  // this will obivously not work
  assert.deepStrictEqual(loggerInfoSpy.mock.calls, { arguments: [2, "No consumer application for given code", "MODEL_ENERGY_FLOW"] });
}) 

Is there a way to have an assertion like this? Basically I want to have something that would look in jest like this:
expect(
  loggerInfoSpy.mock.calls
).toEqual(
  expect.arrayContaining(
    [{ arguments: [2, "No consumer application for given code", "MODEL_ENERGY_FLOW"] }]
  )
);

Even better ofcourse would be an assertion similar to expect(loggerInfoSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...).
Is there any way to add assertions / extend the node:assert module?

Would be interesting to know why some people voted this down. Leaving a comment when voting down would have been helpful.

You'll have to create your own helper function to do this, you can attach it to the assert module yourself if you wish. Here's an example:
const { describe, it, before } = require('node:test'),
      { isDeepStrictEqual } = require('node:util'),
      assert = require('node:assert');


assert.calledWith = function(calls, chk) {
  if(calls.mock)
    calls = calls.mock.calls;
  else if(calls.calls)
    calls = calls.calls;
  for(let call of calls) {
    if(isDeepStrictEqual(call.arguments, chk))
      return true;
  }
  assert.fail(`Expected function to be called with ${JSON.stringify(chk)}`);
}

class Foo {
  bar(a,b,c) {
  }
}

describe('foo', function() {
  let foo;
  before(function(t) {
    foo = new Foo();
  });
  it('expect pass', (t) => {
    let spy = t.mock.method(foo,'bar');
    let args = [ 'asdfa', 24342, {x:'y'} ];
    foo.bar(...args);
    assert.calledWith(spy,args);
  });
  it('expect fail', (t) => {
    let spy = t.mock.method(foo,'bar');
    let args = [ 'asdfa', 24342, {x:'y'} ];
    foo.bar(...args);
    assert.calledWith(spy,args.reverse());
  });
});

▶ foo
  ✔ expect pass (0.588027ms)
  ✖ expect fail (0.490436ms)
    AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Expected function to be called with [{"x":"y"},24342,"asdfa"]
        at assert.calledWith (/tmp/foo/test.js:15:10)
        at TestContext.<anonymous> (/tmp/foo/test.js:38:12)
        at Test.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:206:9)
        at Test.run (node:internal/test_runner/test:631:25)
        at async Suite.processPendingSubtests (node:internal/test_runner/test:374:7) {
      generatedMessage: false,
      code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
      actual: undefined,
      expected: undefined,
      operator: 'fail'
    }

▶ foo (2.386671ms)

ℹ tests 2
ℹ suites 1
ℹ pass 1
ℹ fail 1
ℹ cancelled 0
ℹ skipped 0
ℹ todo 0
ℹ duration_ms 8.105062

✖ failing tests:

test at test.js:34:3
✖ expect fail (0.490436ms)
  AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Expected function to be called with [{"x":"y"},24342,"asdfa"]
      at assert.calledWith (/tmp/foo/test.js:15:10)
      at TestContext.<anonymous> (/tmp/foo/test.js:38:12)
      at Test.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:206:9)
      at Test.run (node:internal/test_runner/test:631:25)
      at async Suite.processPendingSubtests (node:internal/test_runner/test:374:7) {
    generatedMessage: false,
    code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
    actual: undefined,
    expected: undefined,
    operator: 'fail'
  }

